# Need to know about apc ups AVR

Tags: ups

Due to high voltage my mac mini broke down. I am looking for cheap option and found this [apc ups BX600CI](http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=BX600CI-IN). I read its specification which have AVR. I want to know what doest this mean. Its Input voltage is 145V - 290V. What does this mean?

Comment: Are you planning to reverse-engineer this UPS and build one like it? If not, then your question is not suited to this site. If you have a question about a consumer electronic device, the appropriate thing to do would be to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: APC UPSes use PICs, as I'm sure the asker would have realized if they had opened one.

Answer (score 3):

"Automatic Voltage Regulation" as shown on the "Product Overview" tab simply means that the UPS uses an [autotransformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer) or a similar device to boost voltage from below normal levels to proper line voltage without having to otherwise boost voltage drained from the battery to line level.